# Relabeling instance name in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to relabel the `__address__` property in Prometheus without any luck. This is my configuration:

```
      - job_name: 'kafka'
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - kafka-kafka-0.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
            - kafka-kafka-1.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
            - kafka-kafka-2.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
            - kafka-kafka-3.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
            - kafka-kafka-4.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
            - kafka-kafka-5.kafka-kafka-headless:5556
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__address__]
            regex: '(.+)\.'
            target_label: instance
            replacement: ${1}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to take address label and make the instance label like `kafka-kafka-0`, `kafka-kafka-1`, etc... but it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prometheus regexes are anchored, so your regex doesn't match. Add `.*` at the end.